# Simplify expression, skanavi 2.001

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I simplify this expression?

$$
\frac {\sqrt{x}+1}{x\sqrt{x} + x +\sqrt{x}} \colon \frac {1}{x^2 - \sqrt{x}}
$$

#### Solving:

$$
a = \sqrt x
$$

$$
\frac {a+1}{a^3 + a^2 + a} \colon \frac{1}{a^4-a} = \frac{ a(a + 1)(a-1)(a^2 + a + 1) }{a(a^2 + a + 1)}  = (a +1)(a -1)=a^2-1 
$$

#### Anser is: $x - 1$

Comment: ":" being ratio?

Comment: yes this is ratio

Comment: @ozik.dev, did you get Yuri's hint?

Comment: @Vikram, yes thanks, i try to understand his answer :)

Comment: @ozik.dev,$x-1=\sqrt{x}$

Comment: $a^2 = x$ because a = $\sqrt x$

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}:\frac{c}{d}$ implies $ad=bc$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $x^2 - \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x}\Big( (\sqrt{x})^3 - 1 \Big)$ and use the formula $a^3 - 1 = (a -1)(a^2+a+1)$

Comment: thanks, you saved my day :)